# Creating a neural network that is capable of forecasting electricity usage on a range of scales

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series

I have a number of usage patterns for different kinds of customers. Large scale factories and small scale customers or even single devices such as AC units. 
I am trying to create a model with keras that can predict any of these inputs, given proper prior scaling of the input.

When I run a model on each customer individually, the predictions are sort of good.

[image]

Once I train that model on a number of inputs however, the results degrade greatly.

[image]
[image]

Is it possible to train a network that can handle a range of inputs and recognize them as different classes / types. How would such a model have to look like?

This is my current one:

```
model_unif = Sequential()
    # input layer
input_shape = (cfg.DEMAND_ONE_WEEK,)
model_unif.add(Dense(168, input_shape=input_shape, activation='linear'))
model_unif.add(BatchNormalization()) #applying batch normalization now
model_unif.add(Dense(100, activation='linear'))
model_unif.add(Dense(100, activation='linear'))
model_unif.add(Dense(100, activation='linear'))
model_unif.add(Dense(50, activation='linear'))
model_unif.add(Dense(50, activation='linear'))
model_unif.add(Dense(24))
model_unif.add(Activation('linear'))
model_unif.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

Comment: I think this is beyond the scope of SO

Comment: It's honestly not possible to tell the difference which exact questions belong to SO and which belong to statsxchange. I saw way more math based questions on SO than some that I posted on statsexchange and the other way around. Not sure the rigid separation of communities is the right way to go.

Comment: its just my opinion but in general, SO is better for "why doesnt my code work" types of questions. Its definitely possible that someone here might have a good answer for you but this question is more broad, might be better in a machine-learning oriented site.